# custom uiview inside a uiview controller does not show ios

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIView controller and a UIView called GCView.

If my code is just this :

```
self.view = [[GCView alloc] init];
```

I can see my custom view.

When I drag and drop a UIView in the storyboard, assign it to a property called customView

and use that code:

```
self.customView = [[GCView alloc] init];
```

nothing is shown.

I want to use the second approach, because it is more convenient to have some stuff inside the UIView created and handled dynamically, and the others to be statically inside the storyboard and handled in the UIViewController.

Comment: maybe make sure customView is attached properly. try setting its background color or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your view object in the story board is of class GCView. This will call initWithCoder: in your GCView class when the view loads. Once you have that, remove this:

```
self.customView = [[GCView alloc] init];
```

as the object will have already been initialized by the storyboard loading. Make sure all of your initialization calls in the GCView class are in initWithCoder: and not init.

Comment: I tried this, but the initWithCoder is called for ever and the application crashes.

Comment: Can you post your initWithCoder: method and the crash message if there is one? It sounds like you're trying to call it recursively.